# Want equivalent of vim W and E

Tags: navigation

Any easy way to get forward/backword word movement with "word" defined as everything non-whitespace, similar to vim's W and E?

Comment: You may also consider `evil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what vim does, but something like this?

`-` and `^-` represents whitespace syntax and non-whitespace syntax respectively.

```el
(defun my-forward-word ()
  "Forward to the end of the 'word at point' (vim-like)."
  (interactive)
  (skip-syntax-forward "-")
  (skip-syntax-forward "^-"))

(defun my-backward-word ()
  "Backward to the start of the 'word at point' (vim-like)."
  (interactive)
  (skip-syntax-backward "-")
  (skip-syntax-backward "^-"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found (foward-whitespace) I think it's close enough.